# How to read data from GoogleCloud Storage using "gcloud" (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage

I was trying to read data from my goggle 'gcloud' library from pub dev. But there was an error calling,

```
W/DynamiteModule( 9106): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule( 9106): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller( 9106): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

I've use this code to read the folder from my cloud storage,

```
  Future<void> read() async {
   
    if (_client == null)
      _client = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, Storage.SCOPES);
    
    var storage = Storage(_client, 'audio_project');
    var bucket = storage.bucket('audio_bucket');

     var audioList =  await bucket.read("level01/").toList();

    audioList.forEach((element) {
      print("Elements"+element.toString());
    });
    return audioList;
  }
```

In my storage there is a folder, in that there are audio files. Those are the files that i need to read.

```
gcloud: ^0.7.3
googleapis_auth: ^0.2.12
```

These are my dependencies.

```
flutter run --verbose
```

shows

```
[ +141 ms] E/flutter ( 9371): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'read' was called on null.
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): Receiver: null
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): Tried calling: read()
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #1      BaseViewState.getAudios (package:OA/screens/base_view.dart:94:30)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #2      BaseViewState.initState (package:OA/screens/base_view.dart:29:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #3      _LandingPageState.initState (package:OA/screens/dashboard.dart:112:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #4      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #5      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #6      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #7      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #8      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #10     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #11     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #12     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #13     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #14     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #15     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #16     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #18     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #19     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #20     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter ( 9371): #21     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #23     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #24     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #25     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #26     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #27     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #28     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
[   +1 ms] E/flutter ( 9371): #29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #32     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #33     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #34     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #35     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #38     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #40     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #41     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #42     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #43     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
[        ] E/flutter ( 9371): #44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
[   +2 ms] E/flutter ( 9371): #45     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.d
```

Comment: Can you try running your app with `flutter run --verbose` to get a more descriptive error and share it?

Comment: The error message says that you calling a `'read'` function of a null, which is reffering to this line `bucket.read("level01/").toList();`, so your `bucket` is the variable with a null value, which implies on there not existing a bucket name `'audio_bucket'` could you confirm if everything is correct taking these considerations?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes your answer is correct.

Comment: I have added that information into an answer, please consider accepting/upvoting it if it helped you fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you shared after the verbose run says that you calling a `'read'` function of a null, which is referring to this line

```
bucket.read("level01/").toList();
```

That mean that your `bucket` variable is the variable with a null value, which implies on there not existing a bucket with name `'audio_bucket'`. So in order to fix it I suggest you take a look at the GCS bucket and confirm if that is indeed the name of the bucket, as that is where I believe the issue you facing is occurring.

Comment: Yes @Rafael Thank you!